# Why can I call proxy.getClass() inside InvocationHandler's invoke() method?

Tags: java, reflection

This is a modified dynamic proxy example from "Thinking in Java".

```
import java.lang.reflect.*;

interface Interface { void foo(); }

class RealObject implements Interface {
    public void foo() {}
}

class DynamicProxyHandler implements InvocationHandler {
    private Object proxied;
    public DynamicProxyHandler(Object proxied) {
        this.proxied = proxied;
    }
    @Override
    public Object 
    invoke(Object proxy, Method method, Object[] args) 
    throws Throwable {
        proxy.toString();
        return method.invoke(proxied, args);
    }
}

public class ProxyTest {
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        RealObject real = new RealObject();
        Interface proxy = (Interface)Proxy.newProxyInstance(
            Interface.class.getClassLoader(),
            new Class[]{ Interface.class }, 
            new DynamicProxyHandler(real));
        proxy.foo();
    }
}
```

In above example, I call `toString()` method inside `invoke()` method. As I expected, infinite recursion will happen because calling proxy's `toString()` method will invoke the Handler again.

This is how Bruce Eckel said in "Thinking in Java":

> However, be careful when calling methods on the proxy inside
>   `invoke()`, because calls through the interface are redirected through
>   the proxy.

Exception details:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.StackOverflowError
    at DynamicProxyHandler.invoke(ProxyTest.java:19)
    at $Proxy0.toString(Unknown Source)
    at DynamicProxyHandler.invoke(ProxyTest.java:19)
    at $Proxy0.toString(Unknown Source)
    ...
```

But, if I substitute `proxy.getClass();` for `proxy.toString();`:

```
public Object 
invoke(Object proxy, Method method, Object[] args) 
throws Throwable {
    proxy.getClass();
    return method.invoke(proxied, args);
}
```

Everything is ok. No StackOverflowError. No infinite recursion.

I also tried to replace `proxy.toString();` with `proxy.hashCode();` or `proxy.equals("foo");`. They caused StackOverflowError either.

Why is `getClass()` different from `toString()`, `hashCode()`, and `equals()`?

Comment: `getClass()` is a final method implemented by `Obect` class.  It is not overridable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Answer can be found in the documentation for Proxy class: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/reflect/Proxy.html

> An invocation of the hashCode, equals, or toString methods declared in java.lang.Object on a proxy instance will be encoded and dispatched to the invocation handler's invoke method in the same manner as interface method invocations are encoded and dispatched, as described above. The declaring class of the Method object passed to invoke will be java.lang.Object. Other public methods of a proxy instance inherited from java.lang.Object are not overridden by a proxy class, so invocations of those methods behave like they do for instances of java.lang.Object.

Also, I think it has something to do with the fact that the `toString()` method has a default definition:

```
public String toString() {
    return getClass().getName() + "@" + Integer.toHexString(hashCode());
}
```

While `getClass()` (and `wait()`, `notify()` etc.) are defined as:

```
public final native Class<?> getClass();
```

So, to differentiate between which methods will not be proxied you can look fo presence of `final native` in the method definition.